# R: match two data frames and create new column in one

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have two data frames.
One is named "Friends" with the person's id and his/her friends, while the other one is named "Likes" describing the person's actions as shown below. 
I want to create a new column in the second data frame to indicate whether the person likes his/her friend's post or not. 
 How can I do it in R? Thank You.

Friends

```
     id    friend's name
     1     A
     1     B
     1     C
     2     B
     2     E
     2     H
     3     A
     3     F
```

Likes

```
     id     title
     1      1 likes A's post.
     1      1 likes F's post.
     2      2 likes G's post.
     3      3 likes F's post.
     3      3 likes B's post.
```

so I want to create a new column named "likedfriendspost", and the data frame to be like this:

```
    id     title                  likefriendspost
     1      1 likes A's post.         1
     1      1 likes his own post.     0
     2      2 likes G's post.         0
     3      3 likes F's post.         1
     3      3 likes B's post.         0
```

Comment: Read about [merge](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1299871/how-to-join-merge-data-frames-inner-outer-left-right)

Comment: You may have one more table where Details of users are there, so that `1=F`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, merging your two data frames together will be helpful here.

This is one approach using the `tidyverse` packages.

First, extract the friend's name from `title` using an appropriate regex pattern.

Then, merge with `left_join` the two data frames, and for each `id` and `title`, check to see if the `name` is included in `friend_name` (from the `friends` data frame).

```
library(tidyverse)

likes %>%
  mutate(name = sub(".*likes (.+?)('s)? post.", "\\1", title)) %>%
  left_join(friends) %>%
  group_by(id, title, name) %>%
  summarise(likefriendpost = +any(name %in% friend_name))
```

**Edit**: Here is a `data.table` version.

First, initialize `likefriendpost` to zero in `likes` table, and extract `friend_name` in a similar fashion. Then, use `setkey` for sorting and preparing to join on both `id` and `friend_name`. Finally, change `likefriendpost` to 1 where joined on `id` and `friend_name`.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(likes)
setDT(friends)

likes[, `:=`(likefriendpost = 0, friend_name = sub(".*likes (.+?)('s)? post.", "\\1", title))]

setkey(likes, id, friend_name)
setkey(friends, id, friend_name)

likes[friends, on = .(id, friend_name), likefriendpost := 1]
```

**Output**

```
     id title                 name    likefriendpost
  <dbl> <chr>                 <chr>            <int>
1     1 1 likes A's post.     A                    1
2     1 1 likes his own post. his own              0
3     2 2 likes G's post.     G                    0
4     3 3 likes B's post.     B                    0
5     3 3 likes F's post.     F                    1
```

**Data**

```
likes <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3), title = c("1 likes A's post.", 
"1 likes his own post.", "2 likes G's post.", "3 likes F's post.", 
"3 likes B's post.")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-5L))

friends <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L), friend_name = c("A", 
"B", "C", "B", "E", "H", "A", "F")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))
```

Comment: Thank you. However, if the data frames are large, how to use data.table instead of tidyverse?

Comment: @SRT. See edited answer for `data.table` approach. Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Yes it is. Thank you so much!